# HTTPoison.request!/5 raises %HTTPoison.Error with weird reason

Tags: elixir, httpoison

After upgrading to Elixir 1.10.3, a call to `HTTPoison.request!()` raised a `HTTPoison.Error` with `id: nil` and a reason of `{:options, {:sslv3, {:versions, [:"tlsv1.2", :"tlsv1.1", :tlsv1, :sslv3]}}}`. What could cause this? All examples I've seen online assume the reason is an atom.

Comment: I believe this is the same error discussed in the Elixir forum @ https://elixirforum.com/t/erlang-v-23-0-and-httpoison-error/31615  and in the HTTPoison issue tracker @ https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/issues/633
It would be helpful to include your version of Erlang and HTTPoison

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sslv3 was removed from Erlang 23.0 because it is an old and insecure protocol. You need to upgrade hackney to 1.16.0 or higher so that you can get this PR that fixes that issue:

https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/pull/619